# MySql showed me no result with my query

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables which are (model, license, pilot, and person)

```
Model: mid, name
License: mid, pid, licenseDate
Pilot: pid, hireDate
person: pid, firstName, lastName
```

**I want to get the names of pilots who are not licensed to fly any airplane**

I tried this query, but it showed me no result!!!

```
select model.mid, license.pid, license.mid, license.licenseDate, pilot.pid, pilot.hireDate, person.firstName, person.lastName   
from model, license, pilot, person    
where pilot.pid = license.pid and model.mid = license.mid and pilot.pid = person.pid    
and not exists(SELECT null FROM model WHERE pilot.pid = license.pid);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... using inner join.

```
SELECT model.mid, license.pid, license.mid, license.licenseDate, pilot.pid, pilot.hireDate, person.firstName, person.lastName   
FROM model
INNER JOIN license ON (model.mid = license.mid)
INNER JOIN pilot ON (pilot.pid = license.pid) 
INNER JOIN person ON (pilot.pid = person.pid)    
WHERE pilot.pid = license.pid AND model.mid = license.mid AND pilot.pid = person.pid    
AND  pilot.pid != license.pid);
```

Comment: unfortunately it is the same result of my query, I don't know what's the problem with it

Answer (score 0):

Not tested the script, but You can fetch pilots which are not in License table means they're not licensed to fly a plane, then you can join the result with person table to fetch the particular name.

```
select p.firstname, p.lastname
from
(
select pid from pilot 
where not exists (select pid from License where License.pid = pilot.pid)
) DT
inner join person p
on p.pid = DT.pid
```

Comment: unfortunately it is the same result of my query

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT pe.firstName, pe.lastName FROM pilot p
LEFT JOIN license l ON p.pid = l.pid
JOIN person pe ON p.pid = pe.pid
WHERE l.pid IS NULL
```

Comment: unfortunately it is the same result of my query

Comment: Then create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with sample data so that we can see why it is not working... maybe the correct result is not returning any data

Comment: when I tried to post the schema on this website it showed me this error "Schema Creation Failed: Access denied for user 'user_2_59440'@'%' to database 'sadb': "